# VirtualHosting doesn't work. Logs me in through previous session

Tags: virtualhost, httpd.conf

When I log in with one browser session, I have to log in, but when I open another session it has automatically logged me in (as if I've picked up session 1), this does not happen if I use `http://192.168.0.9:9070`

It forces me to log in each time. So I know the application is working, it's just the proxy server that seems to apply the loging to each session (from `http://icerap.limeo.com`).

```
# ************************************************************************
# Start of My stuff <<<------------------------------------------------------
# ************************************************************************




#<Proxy *>
#Order Deny,Allow
#Deny from all
#Allow from 192.168.0
#</Proxy> 

# blog
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName icerap.limeo.com
  ProxyPass          /   http://192.168.0.9:9070/
  ProxyPassReverse   /   http://192.168.0.9:9070/
</VirtualHost>


# www
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName         helpdesk.limeo.com 
  ProxyPass          /  http://192.168.0.9:9055/
  ProxyPassReverse   /  http://192.168.0.9:9055/
</VirtualHost>




# blog
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName         IceCake.limeo.com
  ProxyPass          /   http://192.168.0.9:9000/
  ProxyPassReverse   /   http://192.168.0.9:9000/
</VirtualHost>

# End of Limeo stuff <<<------------------------------------------------------
# ************************************************************************
```

Comment: Could you clarify which URLs you're accessing first, and then after you start the new session? I'm assuming it's the same URL

Comment: Also, how are you enforcing the login? Is it HTTP basic auth, or are you setting cookies, or ...

Answer (score 0):

VirtualHost directives have nothing to do with authentication or logging in.